# If GCC accepts C11 atomic_int casts and clang rejects them, which is correct?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, c11

Suppose I have the following C11 program:

```c
#include <stdatomic.h>

int
main()
{
        int x = 0; // same behaviour if `atomic_int x`, surprisingly
        atomic_int y = (atomic_int) x;
}
```

If I compile this with `gcc` 9, I get no errors.  If I compile it with Apple `clang` 11, I get:

```
foo.c:7:17: error: used type 'atomic_int' (aka '_Atomic(int)') where arithmetic or
      pointer type is required
        atomic_int y = (atomic_int) x;
```

Similar issues abound when using a variety of *godbolt* versions of GCC, Clang, and other compilers that support C11, on various platforms.  This happens regardless of whether `--std=c11` is set.

A quick read of the [draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) says (in 6.5.4) that 'the type name shall specify atomic, qualified,
or unqualified scalar type, and the operand shall have scalar type.', which suggests that the cast is legal - I can't see anything that would say otherwise.

So, my question is this: is `clang` in the wrong here?  Are the other compilers incorrectly accepting this cast?  Is this somewhere in which `clang` and `gcc` are allowed to differ?

(The wider context, incidentally, is that I'm using a third-party program that generates C code that includes, amongst other things, a cast from `intmax_t` to `atomic_int`.  This cast works on `gcc`, which is the sole supported compiler for that program, but fails on `clang` --- and, therefore, macOS's `gcc`, which is an alias to `clang`.  I'm trying to work out where the fault lies --- `clang` for rejecting valid code, the program for generating invalid code, or macOS for pretending a compiler that isn't a drop-in replacement for `gcc` is.)

Comment: There is a bug reported one year ago https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40249

Comment: @GiovanniCerretani ah, I missed that, apologies and thanks!  I wonder why that never got picked up.