"Error: used type 'atomic_long_t' (aka 'atomic_t') where arithmetic or pointer type is required" - Xiaomi mt6765 arm kernel compilation
I am trying to build LineageOS 18.0 from source for an unsupported device (Xiaomi Redmi 6A - codename 'cactus') and I am having issues with building the kernel. The source code I cloned can be found here: https://github.com/xiaomi-mt6765/android_kernel_xiaomi_mt6765.
This is the error message:
In file included from /path/to/los_cactus/kernel/xiaomi/mt6765/arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:14:
/path/to/los_cactus/kernel/xiaomi/mt6765/include/linux/sched.h:3288:3: error: used type 'atomic_long_t' (aka 'atomic_t') where arithmetic or pointer
 type is required
                INIT_WORK(&mm->async_put_work, mmdrop_async_fn);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/los_cactus/kernel/xiaomi/mt6765/include/linux/workqueue.h:224:2: note: expanded from macro 'INIT_WORK'
        __INIT_WORK((_work), (_func), 0)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/path/to/los_cactus/kernel/xiaomi/mt6765/include/linux/workqueue.h:217:19: note: expanded from macro '__INIT_WORK'
                (_work)->data = (atomic_long_t) WORK_DATA_INIT();       \
                                ^               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


If it helps, this is my /path/to/los_cactus/.repo/local_manifests/cactus.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <project path="device/xiaomi/cactus" name="xiaomi-mt6765/android_device_xiaomi_cactus" revision="lineage-17.1" />
  <project path="device/xiaomi/mt6765-common" name="xiaomi-mt6765/android_device_xiaomi_mt6765-common" revision="lineage-18.0-staging" />
  <project path="kernel/xiaomi/mt6765" name="xiaomi-mt6765/android_kernel_xiaomi_mt6765" revision="lineage-18.0" />
</manifest>

And this is where I cloned the source code from: https://github.com/LineageOS/android/tree/lineage-18.0.
It should have just gone through smoothly but the error it is throwing is just indecipherable to me. I think I've looked into the implementation of every variable, function, macro and whatnot that is relevant to the error message and nothing seems to be wrong.
Any thoughts on this?
Thanks in advance.

The error you got seems to be specific for clang compiler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680029/if-gcc-accepts-c11-atomic-int-casts-and-clang-rejects-them-which-is-correct. Not sure whether given kernel code is intended to work with clang: the Linux kernel code is primarily intended for gcc compiler.
